# Is an integral depending on a parameter differentiable?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Consider the following double integral depending on a paramter $x \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
I(x) := \int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-(z-x)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(z-x)t}}{10+\ln^2{t}} \ dt \ dz,
$$

I am trying to find out whether $I(x)$ is differentiable in $x$.
Further denote by
$$
J(x,z) := \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(z-x)t}}{10+\ln^2{t}} \ dt
$$
A naive "differentiation" of $J(x,z)$ w.r.t. $x$ may lead to
$$
\frac{d}{dx} J(x,z)  \overset{?}{=} \int_{ 0 }^{ \infty} \frac{te^{-(z-x)t}}{10 + \ln^2 t} \ dt,
$$
which does not converge if we set $z=x$. Can this imply that $I(x)$ is not differentiable?
I guess one could also try a change of variables through $y :=z-x$ and get
$$
I( z - y) := \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-yt}}{10+\ln^2{t}} \ dt \ dy,
$$
but I am not sure whether this will make it easier to try and differentiate w.r.t. $x$.

---

What criteria can be applied to prove or disprove that $I(x)$ is differentiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your change of variables show that it is constant in $x$, so trivially differentiable. Its **not** $I(z-y)$, but just $I(x)$. Note $y$ has no meaning outside of the integral, and $z$ doesn't exist even as a dummy variable after the change of variable.

In general to differentiate integrals depending on a parameter, you would like to use something called "Leibniz's (Integral) Rule", another keyphrase to google is "differentiation under the integral".

And finally no, the inner integral can explode at one point, this doesn't prevent convergence of the whole integral. For instance $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} < \infty $

Comment: Thanks for the observation. Actually, the original integral I was considering is something like
$$
I(x) := \int_{x}^{\infty} f( z) e^{-(z-x)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(z-x)t}}{10+\ln^2{t}} \ dt \ dz,
$$
where $f(z)$ is continuous and $\lim_{ | z | \rightarrow \infty } f(z) = 0$. I tried to remove $f(z)$ for the start, but I guess that was an oversimplification. Do you have thoughts on this one?

Comment: @Holden Do the same change of variables, you end up with 
$$I(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f( y+x) e^{-y} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-yt}}{10+\ln^2{t}} \ dt \ dy = \int_0^\infty f(y+x) K(y) dy,$$
where $K(y)$ is whatever it is, its not important. If you can differentiate, the answer must be
$$
I'(x) = \int_0^\infty f'(y+x) K(y) dy $$ [snip] actually you might be able to get a better sufficient condition

Comment: @Holden I think your original integral is sufficiently different that it warrants you posting a new question

Comment: I did post [a new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501847/differentiating-an-integral-depending-on-a-paramter), in case you are interested